# Job dependencies in Talend Administration Center with file based trigger

Tags: triggers, talend

i'm trying to set up a dependency between two jobs in the Talend Administration Center. When the first job is finished the second job should start. I don't want to implement it by tRunJob component in one of the jobs. That's why i have set up a file trigger. At the end of the first job, the trigger creates a file in a specified directory. Im not sure at which root directory the file would be searched. I've set up the path but it doesn't start the trigger. Does someone have any experience with that? Or is there an other possibility to set up such an dependency?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct but valid only outside TAC, and we need TAC mainly for job scheduling and for managing dependecy, so you have to develop your jobs separately and independently, then [create your tasks](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendPlatformforMDMwithBigDataStudioUserGuide54EN/I.3.3+Creating+an+execution+task+and+scheduling+it) in TAC and a [execution plan](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendAdministrationCenterUserGuide55EN/4.5.2++Creating+an+execution+plan) to schedule your tasks.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what i was looking for. Big thanks @54l3d